# need to split each line of a text file into a list for summation

Tags: python, string, list

I have a text file containing several lines of numbers. I'm trying to create a quick script to iterate through each line of the file and add the numbers of each line together so as I get a new file I can just enter the name and have it run.

So far, I have this:

```
   def main():
        filename = input("File name: ")
        lists=open(filename, 'r')
        lists = lists.readlines()
        newlists=[]
        print("********")
        for i in range(len(lists)):
            newlists.append(lists[i].strip('\n'))
        finallist=newlists.split(',')

        print(finallist)

    main()
```

This obviously does not work because you can't use .split() on a list, but I don't know how else to separate it properly. Once I get my data into a list of lists I know how to iterate through each item and add them, but I can't figure out this step.

If anyone could even simply point me in the direction of documentation that would explain the process I need to do, I'd appreciate it greatly.

Thanks

Comment: You never close the file that you open. That could be a memory leak. It is more pythonic and a better use of computer resources to use `with open(filename, 'r') as lists`.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
def main():
    filename = input("File name: ")
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        overall_sum = 0
        for line in f:
             overall_sum += sum(map(int, line.split(',')))
        print(overall_sum)
```